# Connect ECONNREFUSED - Backendless

Tags: backendless

Im creating an android application. When a enable real time services from Backendless to a specific table, and a trigger that event. The backendless console shows me this error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000, trying to connect...and i not using Backnedless pro.

Answer (score 0):

we already discussed this issue on the Backendless support forum. I informed you that our product team will be investigating it.
https://support.backendless.com/t/connect-econnrefused/10456

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Sorry, i was so desperate to find an answer :(